# Adding Variables to Nested Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently trying to make a dictionary that has each of the key's values as their own dictionary. I keep getting an error 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.' Relatively new to python, so the more detailed the explanation the better (thanks)!

Ultimately, I want something like this:

```
{ 'q0' : { 'a':'q1' }, 'q1' :{ 'a':'q1' } }
```

---

```
test_dict = {}

initial = '0'
tran = 'a'
final = '1'

test_dict[initial][tran] = final
print(test_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do chain assignment, you haven't define what is the value for `test_dict[initial]`.

There are two ways to do that.

1. You need to define the value for the first layer:

```
test_dict[initial] = {}
test_dict[initial][tran] = final
```

2. Or you can define you nested dictionary using defaultdict, so that you can set the default value for your nested dictionary to be a dictionary without explicit assignment.

```
from collections import defaultdict
test_dict = defaultdict(defaultdict)  # or defaultdict(dict)
test_dict[initial][tran] = final
```